# Post On Facebook Wall With Android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk

how to share post on wall from facebook sdk 4.10.0 in android?

```html
List<String> permissionNeeds = Arrays.asList("publish_actions");
 manager = LoginManager.getInstance();
 manager.logInWithPublishPermissions(this, permissionNeeds);

 manager.registerCallback(callbackManager,
  new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
   @Override
   public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
    
   }

   @Override
   public void onCancel() {
    System.out.println("onCancel");
   }

   @Override
    public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
    System.out.println("onError");
   }
 });
```

I'm Working With This Code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code.

```html
 shareDialog = new ShareDialog(this);
 callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
 shareDialog.registerCallback(callbackManager, new
 FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
   @Override
    public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
@Override
public void onCancel() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Not Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
@Override
public void onError(FacebookException error) {}
 });
```

```html
 if (ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) {
                    //Post Link with Detail On Wall....
                  /*  ShareLinkContent content = new ShareLinkContent.Builder()
                            .setContentTitle("Hello Facebook")
                            .setContentDescription("The 'Hello Facebook' sample  showcases simple Facebook integration")
                            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse("http://developers.facebook.com/android"))
                            .build();*/
                    //Post Image on Wall...........
                    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.naturals1);
                    SharePhoto photo = new SharePhoto.Builder().setBitmap(image).build();
                    SharePhotoContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                            .addPhoto(photo)
                            .build();

                    shareDialog.show(content);
                }
```